# How to show labels columns of 2D-array in VB6

Tags: vb6

I am new to vb6, I need it for my school, I have tried so much, I cant do it
this is my practice
a program that has passengers(Name,FlightNumber,Departure,arrival)
when you type "R" every passenger specification should go to the computer
when you type I every Passenger specification should show 
when you type E the program should finish

I have Used 2dArray which is called Passengers(3,4) because I have four columns
and nested for and an input box for entering information, but I don't know how to show columns labels, therefor user understands which column to type?
and I don't know is it right to use arrays, and list for showing information?
would you please help me with code? I am using vb6
this is my code,is there better any better way?

```
Dim a(5, 4)
Dim i, j As Integer
If Text1.Text = "R" Then
For i = 1 To 5
a(i, 1) = Val(InputBox("Please enter Passenger Name:"))
a(i, 2) = Val(InputBox("Please enter Passenger Flight Number:"))
a(i, 3) = Val(InputBox("Please enter Passenger Departure:"))
a(i, 4) = Val(InputBox("Please enter Passenger Arrival:"))
Next i
ElseIf Text1.Text = "I" Then
Picture1.Cls
Picture1.Print "Passenger"; Space(3); "Value of element"
For j = 1 To 4
Picture1.Print "Passenger"; 1; Space(11); a(1, j); "Passenger"; 2; Space(11); 
a(2, j); 'and other coulmns
Next j
ElseIf Text1.Text = "E" Then
End
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you show the relevant portions of the code you have already?

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you reformat your code

```vb
Dim a(5, 4)
Dim i, j As Integer
If Text1.Text = "R" Then
    For i = 1 To 5
        a(i, 1) = Val(InputBox("Please enter Passenger Name:"))
        a(i, 2) = Val(InputBox("Please enter Passenger Flight Number:"))
        a(i, 3) = Val(InputBox("Please enter Passenger Departure:"))
        a(i, 4) = Val(InputBox("Please enter Passenger Arrival:"))
    Next i
ElseIf Text1.Text = "I" Then
    Picture1.Cls
    Picture1.Print "Passenger"; Space(3); "Value of element"
    For j = 1 To 4
        Picture1.Print "Passenger"; 1; Space(11); a(1, j); "Passenger"; 2; Space(11);
        a(2, j); 'and other coulmns
    Next j
ElseIf Text1.Text = "E" Then
    End
End If
```